# How do I show $SO(n)$ is open and closed in $O(n)$?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

As title, how do I show $SO(n)$ is open and closed subset of $O(n)$?

Is the preimage of closed set under continuous map closed ?

Comment: Yes...in fact, that is one of two equivalent, very usual definitions of "continuous map" between topological spaces.

Comment: First of all, do you know how to give $O(n)$ a topology?

Comment: @John I don't know what open sets look like in $O(3)$ as I can't picture open ball using matrices.

Comment: As $O(n)$ is a subset of $M_n(\mathbb R)$ (the set of all $n \times n$ matrix$, and $M_n(\mathbb R)$ is identified as $\mathbb R^{n^2}$, then $O(n)$ is given the subspace topology.

Comment: So now I can define function $f:O(n) \rightarrow X$ ($X$ just some space) and use the theorem which link continuous function to open sets to say something about $SO(3)$ in $O(3)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the continuous map $\det:O(n)\to\lbrace -1,+1\rbrace$, and $SO(n)$ is the preimage of $\lbrace +1\rbrace$, which is both open and closed in $\lbrace -1,+1\rbrace$, hence $SO(n)$ is both open and closed in $O(n)$.

---

Here's another reasoning: $SO(n)$ is a connected component of $O(n)$, hence closed. But $O(n)$ is locally connected, because it's a manifold, hence $SO(n)$ is open aswell.

Comment: The first proof is nice. But for the second, if you assume already that $SO(n)$ is a connected component of $O(n)$, then there is nothing to proof (it's open and closed)

Comment: Thinks, one thing want to ask, how do I know $det$ is continuous ?

Comment: @SamC observe that $\det$ is just a polynomial in $n^2$ variables.

Answer (score 2):

hint a):
$$
f:M_n(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow M_n(\mathbb{R}) \qquad A \mapsto A^tA
$$
is continous and $O(n)$ is the preimage of a point.

hint b) $\det:M_n(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continous

You only need to show "open": Fix an element of $O(n)\setminus SO(n)$, let's call it $R$. Then
$$
L_R:O(n) \rightarrow O(n) \qquad A \rightarrow RA
$$
is a homoemorphism: What is $L_R(SO(n)) \cup SO(n)$?